# Browser refresh issue. AngularJS and Web API

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Scenario: We are referring third party paid API's in back end web API. And we are requesting those API through our application browser (search button). Whenever we click on search button and after if we refresh browser immediately, then request sending twice. Is there any way we can restrict this.

Comment: Can you please past ajax code here? for better help

Comment: Why is it send twice after refresh? Doesn't the user have to click the button again? The first request should be canceled automatically by the client. In the moment the user refreshes the page.

Comment: The thing is, we searching some keyword by button click. Same keyword we storing in local storage. And if user refresh page that will hit again. If user waits to load UI then, we do not have problem. If user refresh page before loading we causing the issue. Since we are using paid API in backend, it is causing. we canot store all data in local storage or session, becouse data will be changed frequently.